# Bib2gls support for non-ASCII characters or non-english languages; .glstex is unable to load non-ASCII characters

Tags: xetex, luatex, input-encodings, bib2gls

I am trying to incorporate bib2gls into glossaries managment in my project, however I hit into trouble when using my native language (czech) and its diacritics (as far as my knowledge goes, those are non-ASCII, but Unicode acceptable characters).

Showing those explicitly, its "ěščřžýáíéďťň."

As far as my troubleshooting abilities go, I was able to track down the source of the problem in .glstex file, which unable to accept the .bib file with non-ASCII characters.

I hit upon package newunicode, answer might be there, but I dont know how to use it for my specific case.

I am lloking for solution working in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX ideally, or at least one of those. I tryed combination of encodings-package as far as my knowledge goes, but none led to correct display of all the characters (glyphs).

MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

%% Pokyny pro arara:

% arara: xelatex
% arara: bib2gls if found("aux", "glsxtr@resource")
% arara:  xelatex
% arara: bib2gls if found("aux", "glsxtr@resource")
% arara:  xelatex
% arara:  xelatex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside,openright] {book}                %nastavení knihy

\usepackage [czech] {babel} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage [a4paper, twoside, inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, bottom=3cm] {geometry}         

\usepackage{import}     
\usepackage{filecontents}       

\usepackage[record, nopostdot, automake, abbreviations,% 
                    nostyles, stylemods={all}%
                    ]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[selection={all},%
            src={testgls},%
            save-locations=false,%
            ]

%Glossary entries
\begin{filecontents}{testgls.bib}
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
@entry{nonasciichartest,
    name={ačšěřžýáíéťďň},
    description={ačšěřžýáíéťďň}
}
@entry{asciitest,
    name={ASCII test},
    description={abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz}
}
\end{filecontents}{testgls.bib}

\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing
%\pagenumbering{roman}                  %nutné pro kompilovatelnost referencí - hned od začátku nastavit číslování stránek

\thispagestyle{empty}

\printunsrtglossary[type={main}, style={altlistgroup}, title=Slovníček pojmů, toctitle=Slovníček pojmů]

\clearpage

Standard text:

ěščřžýáíéťďň

\end{document}
```

Final note: I also tryed to use magic comments, which also did not led to working solution. Theyre use might be even redundant :)

Thank you very much for any help, tips regarding this complication. Bib2gls is an amazing tool that I would like to learn to use.

Tomas

Comment: You are making testing difficult with all this import/subimport stuff. But beside this is looks as if there is something wrong in bib2gls, it doesn't write correct utf8. Make a bug report.

Comment: The [bib2gls manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/bib2gls.pdf) (page 31) mentions a slightly different way to specify the encoding of the `.bib` file, you could try if that changes anything.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you mr. Fischer for your advice, I have edited my MWE. Next time I wont recreate my document-parts-tree; I though it might be relevant, but most probably it isnt.

Comment: I'm Mrs. Fischer. And I already tested your example and my advice stays: Make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am very sorry for that, did not known Ulrike is Woman name. Thank you for your time, I actually found working solution while reading carefully through bib2gls manual again.
My problem was resolved by adding charset=UTF-8 option into \GlsXtrLoadResources
It is referenced at page 99, among general option of the command...

Comment: Then answer your own question - and make a bug report anyway. The package should be able to detect xetex/luatex and handle this correctly on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ms. Fischer instructed, I am answering my own question (strange).

Solution for this problem lies in adding option "charset=UTF-8" to \GlsXtrLoadResources, leading to:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% arara: xelatex
% arara: bib2gls if found("aux", "glsxtr@resource")
% arara:  xelatex
% arara: bib2gls if found("aux", "glsxtr@resource")
% arara:  xelatex
% arara:  xelatex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside,openright] {book}       
\usepackage [czech] {babel}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage [a4paper, twoside, inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, bottom=3cm] {geometry}         

\usepackage{import}     
\usepackage{filecontents}       

\usepackage[record, nopostdot, automake, abbreviations,% 
                    nostyles, stylemods={all}%
                    ]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[selection={all},%
            src={testgls},%
            save-locations=false,%
            charset=UTF-8%
            ]

%Glossary entries
\begin{filecontents}{testgls.bib}
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
@entry{nonasciichartest,
    name={ačšěřžýáíéťďň},
    description={ačšěřžýáíéťďň}
}
@entry{asciitest,
    name={ASCII test},
    description={abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz}
}
\end{filecontents}{testgls.bib}

\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing

\thispagestyle{empty}

\printunsrtglossary[type={main}, style={altlistgroup}, title=Slovníček pojmů, toctitle=Slovníček pojmů]

\clearpage

Standard text:

ěščřžýáíéťďň

\end{document}
```